# HTML5, Bootstrap 3.3.7 navbar and footer inconsistent between browsers

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

Please could you help me with the following, here's some code snippets of the website I'm writing and the output across all major web browsers:

```
<!-- Bootstrap 3.3.7 -->
<!-- HTML5 Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top sticky">

<!-- HTML5 Footer -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom sticky">

<!-- css -->
/* Override Bootstrap navbar styling */
.sticky {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0px; /* When the element reaches top: 10px, it becomes fixed. */
    z-index: 100;
}

/* Begin navbar styling                    */
.navbar { 
    background-image: none;
}

.navbar-default {
    background-color: #006400;
    color:#fff;
    border-radius:0;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
    color: #fff;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a {
    color: #fff;
    background-color:transparent;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open >a {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #33aa33;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
    color: #fff;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
    background-color:#fff;
}

.navbar-default .icon-bar {
    background-color:#33aa33;
}
/* End navbar styling                      */
```

Chrome 59.0.3071.115
[image: chrome 59.0.3071.115]

Edge 38.14393.1066.0
[image: edge 38.14393.1066.0]

Firefox 55.0b7
[image: firefox 55.0b7]

Opera 46
[image: opera 46]

Safari 5.1.7
[image: safari 5.1.7]

So my question is why are Edge 38.14393.1066.0 and Safari 5.1.7 so different to the other 3 web browsers?

Comment: `position: sticky;` is not supported widely -> http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky; although based on the browsers you done the tests, it should be working on most of them (apart from Safari)

Comment: @Morpheus sorry for taking a while to respond, and thanks for the link and explanation, I totally overlooked the CSS3 property position: sticky;.  I've updated my CSS accordingly and it's working as expected across all major browsers now.

Comment: No problem, glad you got it sorted in the end :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Morpheus, I changed my CSS to the following:

```
/* Override Bootstrap navbar styling */
. sticky {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0px; /* When the element reaches top: 10px, it becomes fixed. */
    z-index: 100;
}
```

Changed to:

```
/* Override Bootstrap navbar styling */
.rhgh-fixed-top {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 100;
}

.rhgh-fixed-bottom {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    z-index: 100;
}
```